# Removing Entries From Dictionaries

Tags: python

Say I have a dictionary with a lot of entries but I only need the first 5-10 entries to be printed, how would I go about doing this? I thought about using a for loop but I cannot find a way to make that work with dictionaries since as far as I am aware you cannot access dictionary values without knowing the key names. I also tried converting the dictionary into a list of tuples but this causes the order of the entries to be changed in an unwanted way. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

For dictionary d, to print the first n values:

```
 print(list(d.values())[:n])
```

If the dictionary represent counts of words and you want the list of the top n words:

```
d = {'red': 4, 'blue': 2, 'yellow': 1, "green":5}      # Example dictionary
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key = lambda kv: -kv[1])  # Sort descending
n = 2                                                  # number of values wanted
print(sorted_d[:n])                                    # list of top n tuples
# Out: [('green', 5), ('red', 4)]
```

You can get words and counts as separate list

```
words, counts = zip(*sorted_d)                         # split into words and values
print(counts[:n])                                      # counts of top n words
# Out: (5, 4)                                          # top n values
```

Another option is to convert the dictionary to a Counter

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(d)
print(c.most_common(n))                               # Shows the n most common items in dictionary
# Out: {'green': 5, 'red': 4}
```

If using the counter, you could also use the counter to count the words as explained by [Counting words with Python's Counter](https://investigate.ai/text-analysis/counting-words-with-pythons-counter/)

Comment: @JohnSmith--do you want the n most common words and their counts?  for instance if `d = {'red': 4, 'blue': 2, 'yellow': 1, "green":5}`;  n = 2` do you want `the list `[('green', 5), ('red', 4)]`?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I want.

Comment: @JohnSmith--does updated answer help with this?

Comment: Yes, this helps me a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If `asd` is your dictionary

```
asd = {'a':'1', 'b':'2', 'c':'3'}

for i, el in enumerate(asd.values()):
    if i < 5:
        print(el)
```

This will print the first 5 values, regardless of the name of the keys.